# vite building issue for svelte-kit

Tags: javascript, svelte, vite

Everytime I run : `npm run dev` in my terminal, I get this error:

```
> enhanzer@0.0.1 dev
> vite dev


Forced re-optimization of dependencies
Error:   Failed to scan for dependencies from entries:
  C:\Users\dell\Desktop\all\enhanzer\enhanzer\node_modules\@sveltejs\kit\src\runtime\client\start.js       

  The service is no longer running
    at C:\Users\dell\Desktop\all\enhanzer\enhanzer\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1073:25
    at sendRequest (C:\Users\dell\Desktop\all\enhanzer\enhanzer\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:693:14)   
    at buildOrContextContinue (C:\Users\dell\Desktop\all\enhanzer\enhanzer\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1071:5)
    at C:\Users\dell\Desktop\all\enhanzer\enhanzer\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:983:11

  VITE v4.3.9  ready in 1130 ms

  ➜  Local:   http://localhost:5173/
  ➜  Network: use --host to expose
  ➜  press h to show help
```

And while it works, it doesn't automatically update on the web browser. I have to manually refresh the page.

I deleted the node modules folder twice, ran `npm cache clean --force`, tried to update vite and npm globally.
My nodejs version is 18

Comment: maybe add the content of `package.json` to the question